# Opposite of "trendy" without a negative meaning

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

I am looking for an opposite to the word *trendy* without giving a meaning that those who adopted the trend are old-fashioned in hindsight. For example,

> Service Oriented Architecture is the trend as of now. But what is trendy in 2014 can become ______ in 2015.

So in 2015, the trend becomes widespread to the extent that it is no longer *trendy*, but not necessarily *old-fashioned*.

**Edit:** I am currently thinking of using *mainstream*. But still any other thoughts are welcome!

Comment: What's the problem with "mainstream"?

Comment: You definitely mean to say *conventional.* See also, *commonplace;* *regular;* *the usual;* *normal;*

Comment: @Nick2253 well, no problem per se - it was not in my mind when I first typed int he question. I was also thinking of "legacy" which has a negative touch in computing world.

Comment: Informal: *so last year.* :)

Comment: It does depend on how you see the previous trendy solutions once they emerge from the brilliance of that exalted position- are they now adopted as mainstream or have they been cast aside in favour of the next trendy solution. Much as I hate the phrase, "business as usual" is now prominent in I.T. and I find myself using it more and more. What was once trendy [and cutting edge stuff,] is now business-as-usual in many organisations"...

Comment: it's interesting- the word u r looking for is probably not the opposite of trendy- that would be old fashioned/outdated. U are looking for a word that means that the technology is not trendy but currently mainstream and heavily used and integrated. that's a positive for a technology, not a negative.

Comment: Prudent. My sister has a very prudent sense of fashion. Which is neat, not-too-loud and neither too gaudy nor bling.

Comment: what is trendy today, can be run-of-the-mill tomorrow.

Comment: "Traditional" works as well.

Comment: Your second sentence would better reflect the state of the 'new ordinary' if you substituted *might be* for *can become:* "But what is trendy in 2014 **might be** ______ in 2015".

Comment: Maybe: "classic"   ?

Comment: "proven technology" is perhaps overdoing it. It's an opposite of trendy and certainly not negative, but it might be _too_ positive.

Comment: The title and the question don't really match. It appears that a negative connotation might not be entirely unwanted. The sample sentence is begging for a negative connotation to balance out the positive connotation of _trendy_. The real issue seems to be finding **the opposite of trendy without implying obsolescence**

Comment: Maybe "established"?

Comment: "trendy" is a charged word, both for "good" mostly by clueless and lemmings and for bad by realists and those that despise lemmings, so trying to come up with an uncharged word to describe last year's lemming-bait may end up being appropriately negatively charged.  @HarrisonPaine You're right and wrong.  "Trendy" appears for a short time to be positive, but later tends to prove useless at best.  The opposite of trendy trends (appropriately) toward declared obsolescence. I see a trend, and I go another way.

Comment: When time has proven something to be reliable it becomes the familiar custom.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're not looking for outmoded or unfashionable, I suggest "**commonplace**".

- Service Oriented Architecture is the trend as of now. But what is trendy in 2014 can become commonplace in 2015"

> commonplace (adj) - an idea, expression, remark, etc., that is not new. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commonplace?show=0&t=1419261014)

Comment: **Established** or **well-established** are slightly more emphatic alternatives.

Answer (score 7):

I think [standard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Standard) may fit the context suggested:

> - commonly used or supplied;  "standard car equipment", "a standard service".

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion, but I find standard rather heavy in this context

Comment: @zencv How exactly do you figure that? _Standard_ is a perfectly normal, unimposing word that doesn’t smack of academia or anything ‘heavy’ like that. I was about to suggest _ubiquitous_, which I can easily see how you’d find too heavy; but _standard_ is no more heavy to me than _the norm_ or _commonplace_ (in fact less heavy than the latter).

Answer (score 6):

If without a negative connotation I think the word **classic** is appropriate.

Comment: A lot of times "classic" means "normal of the past"... which sometimes becomes trendy. Eg, the classic 70s bell-bottoms becoming trendy in the late nineties.

Comment: Yeah, so the right word is for opposite of "trendy" is "classy", not "classic".

Comment: If you want something not negative but actually positive, "**timeless**" might be better than "classic".

Comment: If talking about clothing, music, or the like, then **classic**, **timeless** and so on are excellent.  But for the example in the question, talking about trends in the software industry, they’re rather less natural choices.

Answer (score 5):

Normal.

> "(In computing) Service Oriented Architecture is the trend as of now. But what is trendy in 2014 can become **normal** in 2015"

If I could impose some stylistic changes, I might phrase the sentence as follows:

> "(In computing) Service Oriented Architecture is the trend as of now. But what is trendy in 2014 *may merely be* ***normal*** *by* 2015"

The change is to emphasize the change in status from flashy to the status quo. Without knowing more about what you intend to convey, however, I can't say if this is the right choice for you.

Comment: It's funny you didn't suggest status quo, which is a way better choice than normal.

Comment: i chose commonplace, but mainstream and your suggestion of normal comes very close to the idea that I wanted to convey (+1)

Comment: @KyleHale, Status Quo seems slightly negative to me, so I chose normal. But I can see the irony, as it is a more provocative word and clearly in my vocabulary ;)

Answer (score 5):

$0.02:

But what is trendy in 2014 can become **the norm** in 2015.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! The norm here is for more detailed answers but I think this answer is fine for this question.

Comment: Understood. (I hope there is no norm for detailed comments!)

Comment: @DavidRicherby What's wrong with this question? It's a good answer. Honestly, stack overflow police.

Comment: @monkjack I don't think he has a problem with my answer, he was likely just making sure I am not oblivious to the protocol here as many new users are.

Answer (score 1):

How about "staid" defined by http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/staid as of settled or sedate character; not flighty or capricious.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using trendy as a shorthand for "not widely adopted", my suggestion would be to change *trendy* to ***merely*** *trendy*. This primes the reader that *trendy* is the more negative of the two words, i.e. being mainstream or common or whatever word you insert into the blank  is more desirable than being trendy.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have a different take on the entire statement, I might be completely off the mark here.

> (In computing) Service Oriented Architecture is the trend as of now. But what is trendy in 2014 can become ______ in 2015

The first part of the statement, `(In computing) Service Oriented Architecture is the trend as of now.` it gives me the idea that SOA is becoming mainstream at present. As a developer, something that is a trend presently is something that is an accepted entity and is widely accepted. It also points to something being quite mainstream.
With this context, may I propose,

> (In computing) Service Oriented Architecture is the trend as of now. But what is trending in 2014 can get challenged in 2015

While trying to keep the negative in check, there has to be a reduction of stress in the second part of the sentence (referring to 2015).

Another way I interpret this is that SOA is fairly new, and with it's user base increasing rapidly, applications increasingly migrating to it etc. Hence, the excitement about it needs to be captured. How about something on the lines of:

> (In computing) Service Oriented Architecture has shown huge promise. But what is trending in 2014 can become quite mainstream in 2015

Answer (score 0):

passé. 
adjective 1. no longer fashionable, in wide use, etc.; out-of-date; outmoded.
(http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/passe)

That is the antonym I'd use for "trendy"... but it doesn't appear to be what you're actually looking for. "Old-School" might fit your needs better. Or "commonplace".

Thought of another while reading others' ideas... how about (tech) "du jour"? 
 
Of course, any phrase in French tends to sound disparaging, hehehe...

Comment: Passé most definitely has a negative connotation.

Comment: passè would be wrong here

Comment: I disagree that passè would be totally wrong here.  The actual question only asks that the word doesn't connote "old-fashionedness". Passè connotes a general sense of un-remarkableness, which seems to be the correct tone in the context of the sample sentence.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to "commonplace", "classic", and "normal" (which other posters have suggested), you might also consider "old-hat" or "just another tool in the toolbox".  "Old-hat" has connotations of "something recognizable, comfortable, and easy-to-use" rather than "the opposite of what is in fashion".

"Passé", "old-school", and "old fashioned" have the negative connotations you are looking to avoid.

If fashions change quickly enough, "retro" might be the word you want.  It is hard to imagine things changing so quickly that in just a year, what was old is new again, but maybe your field is like that.

Comment: I think "old hat" has pretty strong negative connotations, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd offer [`retro`](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/retro?s=t). You have `trendy clothing` and `retro clothing` - both are stylish, but the latter is from a previous era.

> of or designating the style of an earlier time:
>   retro clothes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retro_style

Answer (score 0):

I think @DavidRitcherby has it correctly; trendy is not the same as trend.

Trend implies a growing consensus that this is the best approach (whereas trendy is something the elite adopt), the OP sentence uses trend rather than trendy so the suggestion is that in 2014 SOA went from a bleeding edge technology to one that had gained a lot of credibility, which then 2015 would be the entry into the mainstream, where the support for growth plateaus.

Comment: This sounds like your opinion. Do you have any references to back up this analysis?

Comment: I'd say "trend" is more neutral than "trendy".  Even analysis is opinion.  No need to disparage.

Answer (score 0):

The word **contemporary** perhaps?

> belonging to or occurring in the present.

It's not exactly an opposite, but may still be more fitting depending on the context - it's not trendy, but still sufficiently 'modern' to be considered 'normal'.